# How does AVSpeechSynthesizer sounds like a normal voice?

Tags: voice, avspeechsynthesizer

Recently I using AVSpeechSynthesizer to speak text,the voice sounds so stiff,it's not at normal.As the following code:

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *avSpeaker = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc]initWithString:@"我是一名iOS开发者"];
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"zh-CN"];
utterance.volume = 10;
utterance.rate = 0.2;
utterance.pitchMultiplier = 1;
[avSpeaker speakUtterance:utterance];
```

How should I do to make sounds softer,or at least should be normal that,thanks.

Comment: Has everyone helps me?

Comment: default utterance.rate = 0.5 - don’t go to far off, like 0.2 in your case is far too much...

Answer (score 3):

There are different speechVoices of AVSpeechSynthesisVoice, you can use them to get a voice of your choice.Some are softer as you asked, you must try it.

```
th-TH
pt-BR
sk-SK
fr-CA
ro-RO
no-NO
fi-FI
pl-PL
de-DE
nl-NL
id-ID
tr-TR
it-IT
pt-PT
fr-FR
ru-RU
es-MX
zh-HK
sv-SE
hu-HU
zh-TW
es-ES
zh-CN
nl-BE
en-GB
ar-SA
ko-KR
cs-CZ
en-ZA
en-AU
da-DK
en-US
en-IE
hi-IN
el-GR
ja-JP
```

But there is no way to make it softer. utterance.pitchMultiplier may help you little bit, but not at the large extend.
This is the late answer but may help the others.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to add custom voices?

Comment: @Crashalot I think its not possible but not sure. Please better do some R&D.